# find $n$ for which $10^n+3(4^{n+2})+5$ is a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

if $10^n+3(4^{n+2})+5$ is a prime number, then which one is true for $n$

(a) $9$

(b) $5$

(c) $11$

(d) $14$

could some help me with this, thanks

Comment: May I ask if this is a homework problem?

Comment: Try using modulo $3$

Comment: no actually it is from binomial theorem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is greater than $3$ and multiple of $3$. Hence it is not prime.

Answer (score 2):

The number cannot be a prime. Since whatever the value of $n$ may be the power of $10^n+5$ is divisible by $3$ hence the given number is a multiple of $3$. So, it cannot be a prime.

Comment: It is odd.   [space_needed]

Comment: I beg your pardon.

Comment: Now it is better ;)

Comment: Thanks for help @PaoloLeonetti